# View Autocad Drawings inside Delphi application

Tags: delphi, autocad

Is there a way ( ole or component ) to view Atocad 2004-2011 drawings inside Delphi application ?

Comment: [Here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/160200-dxf-delphi-darstellen.html) are some links, mainly regarding DXF. Apparently [Autodesk Design Review](http://www.autodesk.de/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=14623668&siteID=403786) has an ActiveX viewer component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but if you have AutoCad installed on your PC, try importing the ActiveX. It's in the Delphi IDE under Component | Import Component... | Import ActiveX Control.   That'll show the list of available ActiveX gizmos. See if there's anything there that looks like AutoCad. If so, you should be able to make it work ON YOUR PC.  To make it work on ANY PC, you'd need a free or licensed viewer that can handle AutoCad.

Answer (score 4):

CadSoftTools offer [CAD Image DLL](http://www.cadsofttools.com/en/products/cad_image_dll.html) or [CAD Import VCL](http://www.cadsofttools.com/en/products/cad_import_vcl.html)

Answer (score 2):

The Open Design Alliance supports (or used to support, I'm not sure about that one) Delphi in their [TeighaX library](http://opendesign.com/the_oda_platform/TDX).

In the past you have been able to use [DWG Trueview](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=6703438&siteID=123112) as an ActiveX control but that may have been disabled.

Comment: I actually tried with Trueview and i succeed to add to Delphi library the components, but i cant find anywhere some documentation, neither examples - how to use it :|

Comment: Try the usual AutoCAD VBA documentation - it is built on the same framework so it, in theory, should be similar. You won't find any examples because it is _very_ unsupported.